# How to write the given block matrix

Tags: pdftex, matrices, block

```
\begin{center}

\[
   P=\left[
    \begin{array}{c c c c c c c  c c c c}
    a      & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0      &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    0      &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    \vdots &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    0      &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    0      &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    \vdots &   &   &       &   &   &           \\
    0      &   &   &       &   &   &    
    \end{array}
    \right]
\]

\end{center}
```

I want to write the matrix in the following way:

[image]

But I dont know how to write the given matrix in the given form.

I have given the code on how to write the matrix. I just have problem in writing the matrix Q as given in the picture.

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nest matrices:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
P=\begin{bmatrix}
 a & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{matrix} \\
 \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\[1ex] 0 \end{matrix} & \text{\Huge$Q$}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `center` around `\[...\]`.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

With use of the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[
P = \begin{bNiceArray}{ccccc}
a       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0     \\
0       & \Block{4-4}<\huge>{Q} \\
0       &   &   &       &       \\
\vdots  &   &   &       &       \\
0       &   &   &       &   
    \end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

For showed result you need to compile above MWE at least twice.

Answer (score 6):

One more easy method is using `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,multirow}

    \begin{document}

    \[
    P=\begin{bmatrix}
     a & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
     0 \\ 
    0 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\Huge Q}}\\ 
    \vdots \\
    0  &
    \end{bmatrix}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]