# How do I write LaTeX code for matrices of this form?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to write code for a matrix of the form given in the picture below. How can I do it?

[image: matrix]

What I have tried is the following code:

```
\begin{bmatrix} 
     a &      r &      0 & \dots \\  
     r &      b &      s & \dots \\ 0 & s & 0 &  \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \LARGE{D} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
```

which, needless to say, is ugly. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Aside: `\LARGE` is a text-mode command and doesn't work as expected when used in math mode.

Comment: This might help: [How to write the given block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514862)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you employ an `array` environment inside a `\left[ ... \right]` "wrapper". If you think the letter "D" needs to be enlarged a bit, I suggest you do so with the help of the `\scalebox` macro (provided by the `graphicx` package).

The following screenshot shows two ways how these suggestions may be implemented. The one on the left is conceptually simpler, as it employs just one `array` environment. The one on the right is able to achieve perfect vertical (as well as horizontal) centering of the large letter "D" because it employs nested `array` environments as well as the TeX-primitive directive `\vcenter`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\scalebox' macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}
\[
\left[ \begin{array}{cc|cccc}
   a & r & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
   r & b & s & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
   \hline
   0 & s & \\
   0 & 0 & \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \multicolumn{4}{c}{%
      \smash{\scalebox{2}{$D$}}} \\
   0 & 0 & \\
\end{array} \right]
\qquad 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc|cccc}
   a & r & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
   r & b & s & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{%
     \begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
       0 & s \\
       0 & 0 \\
       \vdots & \vdots \\
       0 & 0 
     \end{array}
   } &
   \multicolumn{4}{c}{%
     \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
       \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{$D$}}}
     \end{array}
   }
\end{array} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer(+1)

Answer (score 13):

With `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cc|c ccc}[margin]
  a    & r      & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0    \\
  r    & b      & s & 0 & \Cdots & 0    \\
\hline
  0    & s      & \Block{3-4}<\huge>{D} \\
\Vdots  &\Vdots                         \\
  0     & 0
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

After at least two compilation you will get:

[image]

**Edit:**
Now in matrix code is considered @Mico and my comments below.

Comment: @Mico, termination of the last row is superfluous  (removed now). In this particular case  I also could skip ampersands in ara of block. I do not understand which zeros I should skip.

Comment: @Mico, I see now. In my previous comment  I mentioned this with other words. I will consider this in my answer.

Comment: Huh, @Mico you are right again. I lost termination of matrix row with `\bloc` . Now is added and MWE can be compiled without error. It gives showed matrix image.